# Is there a better way to replicate a column array n times in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, transpose, google-sheets-query

I need to formulaic solution to copy a column range stacking on top of itself a given number of times.  I found one ugly solution by incorporating a sequence function (to get 1,2,3...n) into an arrayformula for a text operation (Left).  The Left operation does nothing but return the original value, but gives me the opportunity to include the sequence array.

There must be a better way to do this.

**Problem**:  Write a formula that creates a column where a named column range is stacked on top of each other an arbitrary number of times.  Must be a single formula as other users will need this to self adjust to a new length automatically.

```
=flatten( transpose( arrayformula( left( Column_Range,len( Column_Range ) + 0 * 
 sign( sequence( 1,Number_of_Times_To_Repeat ) ) ) ) ) )
```

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired result

Answer (score 1):

could be written as:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FLATTEN(TRANSPOSE(LEFT(A1:A5, LEN(A1:A5)*SIGN(SEQUENCE(1, C1))))))
```

[image]

---

or:

```
=INDEX(FLATTEN(TRANSPOSE(LEFT(A1:A5, LEN(A1:A5)*SIGN(SEQUENCE(1, C1))))))
```

or:

```
=INDEX(FLATTEN(TRANSPOSE(LEFT(A1:A5, LEN(A1:A5)*TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&C1))^0)))))
```

or:

```
=INDEX(FLATTEN(TRANSPOSE(LEFT(A1:A5, LEN(A1:A5)*TRANSPOSE(SIGN(ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&C1))))))))
```

or:

```
=INDEX(FLATTEN(TRANSPOSE(LEFT(A1:A5, LEN(A1:A5)*SPLIT(REPT(1&"♀", C1), "♀")))))
```

or:

```
=INDEX(FLATTEN(TRANSPOSE(LEFT(A1:A5, LEN(A1:A5)*COLUMN(INDIRECT("A1:"&ADDRESS(1, C1)))^0))))
```

or:

```
=QUERY(FLATTEN(SPLIT(REPT("♀"&JOIN("♀", A1:A5), C1), "♀",,)), "offset 1")
```

or:

```
=FLATTEN(SPLIT(REPT(QUERY(A1:A5,,9^9)&" ", C1), " ",,))
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Solution 1

Here is a way without `FLATTEN`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  VLOOKUP(
    1 + MOD(
          SEQUENCE(C1 * MAX(ROW(A:A) * (A:A <> ""))) - 1,
          MAX(ROW(A:A) * (A:A <> ""))
        ),
    {ROW(A:A), A:A},
    2,
    0
  )
)
```

`MAX(ROW(A:A) * (A:A <> "")` inside `ARRAYFORMULA` just gives you the row number of the last non-empty cell. The rest is quite straightforward.

[image]

---

#### Solution 2

And here is a `FLATTEN` solution without `LEFT`:

```
=FLATTEN(
  ARRAYFORMULA(
    ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(
      TRANSPOSE(A:A),
      1,
      MAX(ROW(A:A) * (A:A <> ""))
    ) & IF(SEQUENCE(C1), "")
  )
)
```